# Find matching string from List of Class/Object

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I have an array of string :

```
string[] PropertyIds= new string[5];
```

A `List` of Class(`Property`)

```
List<Property> properties = new List<Property>();
```

The class `Property` has following fields:
`PropertyId` (string) and `PropertyDesc` (string)

I have to find all the values of PropertyId  in array PropertyIds, which are not in List properties.

e.g.

```
 string[] PropertyIds= new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
List<Property> properties = new List<Property>()
{ 
  new Property("one","This is p1"),
  new Property("Five","This is p5"),   
  new Property("six","This is p6"),
};
```

Then my result should be **two** and **three**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) to get difference from two sequences:

```
var result = PropertyIds.Except(properties.Select(p => p.PropertyId));
```

Comment: If PropertyId defined in class Property is of type integer.
The how can I then get the difference from two sequences?

Thanks

Comment: @palakmehta use `Select(p => p.PropertyId.ToString())`